# Using LINQ to remove elements from a List<T> where Matching Items Take

Tags: c#, linq

i Know i can do loop but i want more simple way

**I find it difficult to explain the question. I would be very happy if someone would edit and explain my question**

```
 exposur = exposur.Where(p => p.Campaigns.ID == Camp.Campaign.ID)
                  .Take(10)
                  .ToList()
                  .RemoveAll(x => x != null);
```

I have a list of objects and I want where to have a match to take first 10 and remove who is from the list
Sorry for my english

Comment: A loop *is* simpler.

Comment: You have to give more context. What do you want to do, ...

Comment: Your query currently makes little sense. Please explain what you want to do

Comment: I have a list of objects and I want where to have a match to take first 10 and remove who is from the list Sorry for my discovery

Comment: So you want to get first 10 items, that match a condition?

Comment: yes and remove at

Comment: What does this not do?

Comment: @krillgar 1. it won't compile and 2. if it did (assume `RemoveAll` returned the list), it'd return an empty list.

Comment: So you actually want to remove from collection first 10 items that matches predicate?

Comment: It doesn't compile because `RemoveAll()` returns the number of elements that were removed. You can't assign that to a collection. So you'd have to do it as a separate operation after you assign it. That, or replace it with a `Where()`. For your second question, your code does exactly what you're telling it to do. You need to explain why an empty list is bad.

Comment: @krillgar it's bad because it's not what the code is meant to do, is it? The requirement is 'remove first 10 items that match a condition'. The code as written would always remove every item in the list.

Comment: OK, now that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var toRemove = exposur.Where(p => p.Campaigns.ID == Camp.Campaign.ID).Take(10).ToList();
exposur.RemoveAll(p => toRemove.Any(z => z == p));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it would be easier to exclude them in the first place:

```
authorsList = authorsList.Where(x => x.FirstName != "Bob").ToList();
```

However, that would just change the value of authorsList instead of removing the authors from the previous collection. Alternatively, you can use RemoveAll:

```
authorsList.RemoveAll(x => x.FirstName == "Bob");
```

If you really need to do it based on another collection, I'd use a HashSet, RemoveAll and Contains:

```
var setToRemove = new HashSet<Author>(authors);
authorsList.RemoveAll(x => setToRemove.Contains(x));
```

Comment: you can edit on this code and will be solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ Except method to filter collection:

```
exposur = exposur.Except(exposur.Where(p => p.Campaigns.ID == Camp.Campaign.ID).Take(10))
                 .ToList();
```

Since you got duplicates in your collection, the easiest way of removing first 10 items in collection without storing their index will be use `RemoveAll` with counter of removed items:

```
var counter = 0;
exposur.RemoveAll(p => p.Campaigns.ID == Camp.Campaign.ID && counter++ < 10);
```

This will modify original list `exposur` and remove first 10 items that match a predicate, without touching other duplicates.

Comment: For efficiency, you may want a `.ToList()` after the `.Take(10)`. but, overall, this is the best answer.

Comment: I tried this problem and I have many lines that repeat themselves and it deleted a lot more than I should anyway thank you for the investment

Comment: @JamesCurran why would that be more efficient? You can see in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,cebd1476aa53fa04) that each sequence is only enumerated once.

Comment: Good to know.  (Also good to discover the Except() doesn't work like I assumed -- it also removes all duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

From your clarification in the comments, you need to remove the first 10 items in your list that match your conditions.

Your original code was this:

```
exposur = exposur.Where(p => p.Campaigns.ID == Camp.Campaign.ID)
                 .Take(10)
                 .ToList()
                 .RemoveAll(x => x != null);
```

The reason this did not work was because once you call `.ToList()` on the third line, you now create a new collection, separate from your original `exposur` variable.

The reason that did not compile is because `.RemoveAll()` returns an `int`, which is the number of items that were removed. That can't be assigned to your `IEnumerable<T>`.

What you'll need to do is to first get the ones you want to remove:

```
var toRemove = exposur.Where(p => p.Campaigns.ID == Camp.Campaign.ID)
                      .Take(10)
                      .ToList();
```

With this new collection, you can remove those from the other set.

```
exposur.RemoveAll(x => toRemove.Contains(x));
```

You don't need to re-assign that. Again, it returns the number that were removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var exposur = exposur.Where(p => p.Campaigns.ID == Campaign.ID).Take(10).ToList();
exposur.RemoveAll((x) => x!=null);
```

Comment: This will result in an empty list. `x` can never be null.

Answer (score 0):

Youu can use this code also:

```
var stuffToRemove = exposur.SingleOrDefault( s => s.Campaigns.ID == Camp.Campaign.ID )
if( stuffToRemove.ID != 0 )
{
    exposur.Remove( stuffToRemove );
}
```